# Java - How to make JComboBox of non-String objects display String names?

Tags: java, string, swing, object, jcombobox

[image: Imgur]

I would like to make the `JComboBox` component display `String` names, rather than references. However, I don't know how that is done.

Below shows my codes:

```
public class Properties extends JPanel implements ItemListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8555733808183623384L;
    private static final Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(130, 80);
    private JComboBox<Category> tileCategory;

    public Properties() {
        tileCategory = new JComboBox<Category>();
        tileCategory.setPreferredSize(SIZE);
        tileCategory.addItemListener(this);

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(16, 1));
        loadCategory();
    }

    private void loadCategory() {
        //Obtains a HashMap of Strings from somewhere else. All of this is constant, so they
        //aren't modified at runtime.
        HashMap<Integer, String> map = EditorConstants.getInstance().getCategoryList();

        DefaultComboBoxModel<Category> model = (DefaultComboBoxModel<Category>) this.tileCategory.getModel();
        for (int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++) {
            Category c = new Category();
            c.name = map.get(i + 1);
            model.addElement(c);
        }
        this.add(tileCategory);
    }
}
```

The only thing I know is that I passed `Category` class to `JComboBox`. Below shows the `Category` class:

```
public class Category {
    public String name;
}
```

And that's about it.

My only goal is to get the `Category.name` member variable show up in the `JComboBox` drop-down list, where the rectangle is marking in the picture.

Can anyone show me how this is done? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `JComboBox` uses a `ListCellRenderer` to allow you to customise how the values are rendered.

Take a look at [Providing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer) for more details

For example...

```
public class CategoryListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        if (value instanceof Category) {
            value = ((Category)value).name;
        }

        return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    }

}
```

Then you simply specify the render to the combobox

```
tileCategory.setRenderer(new CategoryListCellRenderer());
```

Now, having said that, this will prevent the user from been able to use combo boxes built in search feature.

To that end, check [Combo Box With Custom Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/combo-box-with-custom-renderer/) for a possible work around.  This is authored by our very own camickr

Comment: You have to love blind down voting. It does nothing to allow people to either learn from or improve the answer

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but a renderer will break accessibility and clipboard operations (and, as you mentioned, keyboard navigation).  It’s better to make a wrapper class with a customized `toString` method.

Comment: @VGR While I agree with you primary statement, accessibility and clipboard operations can be mended, as to the keyboard operations, let's just say the API needs a better design, but to overriding `toString` for presentation - this is possibly the worse thing that can be done, because the object won't always be rendered in the same way for all situations, `toString` is better left for debugging, but that's MHO ;)

Comment: Correct.  That’s why I recommend a custom wrapper class (like, say, `CategoryItem`), rather than modifying Category.toString.

Comment: @vgr IMHO it's to limited, unless you're suddenly going to inject html into the `toString` method as well :P

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to override the `toString()` method of your class. This is not a very robust solution, but gets the job done.

```
public class Category {
    public String name;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: `toString` is a poor choice for making rendering decisions, you may not always want to render the value the same way in various components, this is why renderers exist.  `toString` should be constrained to providing debug information

Comment: @MadProgrammer DefaultXxxRenderer is about toString (Edit) and allows two the same (descriptions as) Items in JList/JComboBox without indexing issue (otherwise returns nearest index)

Comment: @mKorbel But modifying the a class's `toString` method simply for presentation purposes is a bad idea. Agreed, it's a pretty simple class, but if it becomes more complex and the OP wants to display it differently in this combo box or that list...then they run into problems, just saying...

Comment: You are absolutely right, that's why i added the comment about it. But it's the quickest way to accomplish, what OP wanted.

Comment: @MadProgrammer see my edit to my original comment, I'm hope that you know about this issue

Comment: OP here, checking out ModProgrammer's edit right now.

Comment: @MadProgrammer this is old issue about DefaultXxxRenderer (works by default, as standard, can't be override) you can reduce possible issues by using BasicXxxRenderer for JComboBox

Comment: @tom_mai78101 by default to avoid to set any value in DefaultXxxRenderer, do this job only in BasicXxxRenderer (make me sence to show description and selection returns index, but HashWhatever missing internal indexing)

Comment: @mKorbel I just have a personal issue with using `toString` for the purpose of displaying viewable data and prefer to use a render as it resolves me of the issues where `toString` might change or I want to display the content differently, that's just me.  I won't downvote a person for suggesting it...just have my little rant ;)

Comment: I won't downvote that either as I'm just implementing a very basic class object, and mKorbel's solution is a more easier one. However, since the `JComboBox` is an level editor's main component, I'm more inclined to use a custom renderer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer [please to see Robs(top two)](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/?s=jcombobox)

Comment: @MadProgrammer agree, agree, agree :-), but I think that this coint has tow sides (old and wrong desicions, based on premature array)

Comment: @mKorbel See the last paragraph of my answer ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer original idea was toString there too, changed by kleopatras comment(s)

Comment: @tom_mai78101 btw you question is poor and bad described, missed an SSCCE/MCVE

Comment: @mKorbel It's a shame that the `ListCellRenderer` wasn't extended in such a way to provide this functionality directly, so you could specify it when setting the renderer...

Comment: @mKorbel Really? I thought I nailed it. Dang...  :'( I hoped I can get feedback on what's wrong with my question that fails to meet the SSCCE/MCVE threshold.

Comment: Holy s that's a lot of comments :D

Comment: @tom_mai78101 yes short, runnable, compilable with harcoded value in local variable, nothing else

Comment: @MadProgrammer important is fact that without an external array you cant be able to put two Items with the same value in JList, not to returns its index (ListSelectionListener, getSelectedXxx, etc), retruns coordinates from nearest or last (never interesting about somehow, only to remember this issue)

Comment: @mKorbel I see now. There are two reasons I can't show those codes, (1) It's massive, (2) Too much effort to effective provide short concise codes to replace that. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @tom_mai78101 (my view) OPs effort to attract good answers, creates real limits to avoiding the wider answer, and don't to use HashMap as main array for Swing GUI, use util.List instead, always ....