# Fill ComboBox with Object Arraylist field

Tags: java, arraylist, combobox, jcombobox

I've found the way to get the toString value, like this:

```
comboBox_Car.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(cars.toArray()));
```

But I can't find a way as fast as this to get only one field, like "colour" (of the car).

Comment: Do you understand the question yourself?

Comment: Yes, I'm loading the comboBox just with the values, this way:
`for (Car c:cars)
   comboBox_Car.addItem(e.getColour());`
But I wonder if I can set the arrayList into the model only showing a desired field.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Sorry, ninja edit, look up there!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java - How to make JComboBox of non-String objects display String names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24179793/java-how-to-make-jcombobox-of-non-string-objects-display-string-names)

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: If your collection of Cars contains two blue cars, do you want your JComboBox to show blue twice in its item list?